# Cannot call a function from init block because of val property

Tags: coding-style, kotlin

I'd like to initialize my class's properties.
Because I'm using heavily the functional elements of Kotlin, I'd like to put these initializations to well named functions, to increase readability of my code.
The problem is that I cannot assign a val property, if the code is not in the init block, but in function which is called from the init block.

Is it possible to take apart initialization of a class, to different functions, if the properties are vals?

Here is the code:

```
    val socket: DatagramSocket = DatagramSocket()
    val data: ByteArray = "Cassiopeiae server discovery packet".toByteArray()
    val broadcastAddresses: List<InetAddress>

    init {
        socket.broadcast = true
        val interfaceAddresses = ArrayList<InterfaceAddress>()
        collectValidNetworkInterfaces(interfaceAddresses)
        collectBroadcastAddresses(interfaceAddresses)
    }

    private fun collectValidNetworkInterfaces(interfaceAddresses: ArrayList<InterfaceAddress>) {
        NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces().toList()
                .filter { validInterface(it) }
                .forEach { nInterface -> nInterface.interfaceAddresses.toCollection(interfaceAddresses) }
    }

    private fun collectBroadcastAddresses(interfaceAddresses: ArrayList<InterfaceAddress>) {
        broadcastAddresses = interfaceAddresses
                .filter { address -> address.broadcast != null }
                .map { it.broadcast }
    }
```

Of course it's not compiling, because *collectBroadcastAddresses* function tries to reassign the *broadcastAddresses* val. Although I don't want to put the code of this function to the init block, because it's not obvious what the code is doing, and the function name tells it very nicely.

What can I do in such cases? I'd like to keep my code clean, this is the most important point!

Comment: Can we use lateinit like: lateinit val broadcastAddresses: List<InetAddress>?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way of approaching the problem is to use [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) to initialize fields:

```
class Operation {
    val socket = DatagramSocket().apply { broadcast = true }
    val data: ByteArray = "Cassiopeiae server discovery packet".toByteArray()
    val broadcastAddresses = collectBroadcastAddresses(collectValidNetworkInterfaces()) 

    private fun collectValidNetworkInterfaces() =
        NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces().toList()
            .filter { validInterface(it) }
            .flatMap { nInterface -> nInterface.interfaceAddresses }

    private fun validInterface(it: NetworkInterface?) = true

    private fun collectBroadcastAddresses(interfaceAddresses: List<InterfaceAddress>) {
        interfaceAddresses
            .filter { address -> address.broadcast != null }
            .map { it.broadcast }
    }
}
```

Notice how the `socket` field initialization uses [`apply`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html) extension.

I often find it useful to extract collection manipulation routines into extension methods:

```
class Operation {
    val socket = DatagramSocket().apply { broadcast = true }
    val data: ByteArray = "Cassiopeiae server discovery packet".toByteArray()
    val broadcastAddresses = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()
        .collectValidNetworkInterfaces { validInterface(it) }
        .collectBroadcastAddresses()

    private fun validInterface(it: NetworkInterface?) = true
}

fun Iterable<InterfaceAddress>.collectBroadcastAddresses(): List<InetAddress> =
    filter { address -> address.broadcast != null }.map { it.broadcast }

fun Enumeration<NetworkInterface>.collectValidNetworkInterfaces(isValid: (NetworkInterface) -> Boolean = { true }) =
    toList()
        .filter { isValid(it) }
        .flatMap { nInterface -> nInterface.interfaceAddresses }
```